# Haskell cannot get right type from ':' cons operator

Tags: haskell

I am getting an error where I am trying to use map in a depth first search algorithm to test paths to contain the goal cell in a maze that is undirected, and without cycles. where I am running into trouble is with the recursive call with map.

Here is my code:

```
type Maze = [[Cell]]

data Cell = Cell { top, left, right, bottom :: Bool }

type Pos = (Int, Int)

type Path = [Pos]

findPath :: Maze -> Path
findPath [] = []
findPath  maze = dfs maze [] (-1,-1) (1,1) 

dfs :: Maze ->Path -> Pos -> Pos -> Path
dfs maze trail prev curr  
    | (curr == goal) = reverse $ goal : trail -- ?
    | (null adj)     = []
    | otherwise      = dfs maze (curr : trail) curr `map` (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)
    where   c = maze!!(fst curr- 1)!!(snd curr - 1)
            goal = (length maze, length (maze!!0))



adj:: Cell -> Int -> Int -> Pos ->Path
adj c x y prev =     if (top c && prev /= (x-1, y)) then [(x-1, y)] else [] ++  
                     if (left c && prev /= (x, y-1)) then [(x, y-1)] else [] ++  
                     if (right c && prev /= (x, y+1)) then [(x, y+1)] else [] ++  
                     if (bottom c && prev /= (x+1, y)) then [(x+1, y)] else []
```

what I expect with `dfs maze (curr : trail) curr 'map' (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)` is that I apply a function `f::Pos->trail` to each element in `[Pos]` but what the `(curr : trail)` gives is a `[Path]` rather than a `Path`

The error stack gives me is as follows:

```
stack: WARNING! Expecting stack options comment at line 1, column 1
stack: WARNING! Missing or unusable stack options specification
stack: WARNING! Using runghc without any additional stack options

SolveMaze.hs:77:24: error:
    * Couldn't match type `[Pos]' with `(Int, Int)'
      Expected type: Path
        Actual type: [Path]
    * In the expression:
        dfs maze (curr : trail) curr
          `map` (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)
      In an equation for `dfs':
          dfs maze trail prev curr
            | (curr == goal) = reverse $ goal : trail
            | (null adj) = []
            | otherwise
            = dfs maze (curr : trail) curr
                `map` (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)
            where
                c = maze !! (fst curr - 1) !! (snd curr - 1)
                goal = (length maze, length (maze !! 0))
   |
77 |     | otherwise      = dfs maze (curr : trail) curr `map` (adj c (fst curr)
 (snd curr) prev)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am sorry if this is a really basic problem for you Haskell wizards but I've been staring at this for so long that I can't take it and needed to reach out for help. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of text and instead post the text.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I've edited and fixed this now

Comment: The error is due to the fact that ``dfs maze (curr : trail) curr `map` (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)`` is a list of paths. to see this, remember that `dfs maze (curr : trail) curr :: Pos -> Path` and that `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, in this case we have `b ~ Path` so we end up with `[Path]`. How to resolve this depends on what you want to achieve, maybe take the head, maybe use listToMaybe(thus returning a `Maybe Path` instead of an error when there are no paths). Also, a line above that `null adj` doesn't compile either, because `adj` is a function.

Comment: @M.Aroosi right, I see what you're saying I'll have to do some reading about how maybe works to understand exactly to solve this in the context of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets zoom in on two lines.  First is the type of dfs:

```
dfs :: Maze ->Path -> Pos -> Pos -> Path
```

So dfs when fully applied returns a `Path`, great.

We also have the definition of dfs, which must return a Path, is:

```
dfs maze (curr : trail) curr `map` (adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev)
```

Or with some simplifications to make explicit what is going on:

```
map (dfs and some args) (some list)
```

So dfs must return a path, so says the type, but the definition shows it as returning a list of paths.

What you seem to want is try to descend into one of the adjacent positions and perform a depth first search then descend into the next possible path, taking advantage of lazy evaluation along the way - great!

1. Lets change dfs to returning a list of Paths (`[Path]`) - that will be a list of solutions or non-solutions (`[]`) if a dead end is found.  Change `reverse ...` to `[reverse ...]`.  and `map` to `concatMap`.
2. It doesn't make sense to ask if a function is null, I think you ment the application of `adj` such as `null (adj c (fst curr) ...`.
3. Find path now has to select one of the list of solutions now returned by dfs - the first one should suffice.  You can use `listToMaybe` to get a `Maybe Path` result.

.

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

type Maze = [[Cell]]    
data Cell = Cell { top, left, right, bottom :: Bool }    
type Pos = (Int, Int)    
type Path = [Pos]

findPath :: Maze -> Maybe Path
findPath [] = Just []
findPath  maze = listToMaybe $ dfs maze [] (-1,-1) (1,1)

dfs :: Maze ->Path -> Pos -> Pos -> [Path]
dfs maze trail prev curr
    | (curr == goal) = [reverse $ goal : trail] -- ?
    | (null adjVal)  = []
    | otherwise      = dfs maze (curr : trail) curr `concatMap` adjVal
    where   c = maze!!(fst curr- 1)!!(snd curr - 1)
            goal = (length maze, length (maze!!0))
            adjVal = adj c (fst curr) (snd curr) prev

adj:: Cell -> Int -> Int -> Pos ->Path
adj c x y prev =     if (top c && prev /= (x-1, y)) then [(x-1, y)] else [] ++
                     if (left c && prev /= (x, y-1)) then [(x, y-1)] else [] ++
                     if (right c && prev /= (x, y+1)) then [(x, y+1)] else [] ++
                     if (bottom c && prev /= (x+1, y)) then [(x+1, y)] else []
```

There are lots of other things you can clean up if you so desire.

- `[]` to signify a failed path instead of `Maybe Path`.  If the first depth-first search fails then your returned "solution" will be `[]`.
- Use of `!!` and assumption the input is not jagged.  You could use an array.
- Verbose definition of `adj` that could use guards instead.

Comment: Your post has helped me immensely and I am very impressed with how well written it is, but I am now running into a `Prelude.!!: negative index` error which is frustrating because there is no line number referenced and removing the possibility of a negative value in a `Pos` type still causes the error